How to clone database in Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio
So I have two databases on the same server

DB_TEST
DB_DEVELOP

I want to make a full copy of the DB_TEST with all of the data and the table structures and everything and alter the DB_DEVELOP to be the same.
I know I made something similar when I was creating the DB_DEVELOP, but I am not sure how to do it now and I want to leave the DB_DEVELOP the same name and permissions as it has so that I can work on the application in the develop mode but using the DB_DEVELOP database so I dont braek something in the DB_TEST database that is going to be a production database later
What I tried
Create a backup of the DB_TEST but I cannot see it in the DB_DEVELOP when I click on restore.
Script database as CREATE To but when I run the script in the DB_DEVELOP it does not work.
Script database with schema and data did not insert all the data from the first database.
Copy database which results in a following error:

It is important that the name and the destination database remain the same.
I tried to delete the Develop database to create a new one as described in an answer on similar question with getting an error: 3702
I am not aware that any users are using the database my application is not running not at least the version that connects to this DB and in my SSMS I don't have any panes open with the said database


unfortunately not I will update the question so it will show what happen when I try to copy database

You can't have 2 databases with the same name on the same server, they must be unique.

@Alejandro I want to update my existing database DB_DEVELOP with the DB_TEST I hope it is more clear now.. I want to alter an existing database DB_DEVELOP with all of the contents from DB_TEST

Most likely the easiest approach is to just drop DB_DEVELOP and backup/restore from test as the duplicate question says. Deleting the data and reinsert can be done, but most likely you'll have to bump though the FKs, checks and other integrity measures as you do.

@Alejandro Im having issues with Deleting the database I have edited the question

As the message says, you have some connections open to the DB. In use databases cannot be deleted. Run sp_who to find out what's using them and optionally kill the connections (it could even be a query window on SSMS itself).

@Alejandro thanks that was it my gitlab runner was using the DB can you please post an answer so I can accept it ?

First, create­ a backup of the DB_TEST database.
To do this, run the following SQL command:
BACKUP DATABASE DB_TEST TO DISK = 'C:\path\to\backup\DB_TEST.bak';

Ne­xt, restore the backup as a ne­w database. This will create a copy of the­ original DB_TEST database. We'll call the ne­w database DB_DEVELOP_TEMP. Run the following SQL commands to restore­ the backup:
USE master;

RESTORE DATABASE DB_DEVELOP_TEMP FROM DISK = 'C:\path\to\backup\DB_TEST.bak'
WITH MOVE 'DB_TEST' TO 'C:\path\to\your\database\DB_DEVELOP_TEMP.mdf',
MOVE 'DB_TEST_log' TO 'C:\path\to\your\log\DB_DEVELOP_TEMP_log.ldf',
REPLACE;


Is it possible to not create a new database and just move the backup to my existing one ?

What do you mean "move the backup to the new one", @jakubpodhaisky ? Especially when you state that you don't want to create a new one (so there is no new database).  Your comment doesn't make sense.

In the answer they are saying "restore the backup as a ne­w database. This will create a copy of the­ original DB_TEST database. We'll call the ne­w database DB_DEVELOP_TEMP."
I already have a database called DB_DEVELOP I want to update it so it reflects the current DB_TEST with all the  tables and data @ThomA

Then just change the name of the database target, and file names appropriately, @jakubpodhaisky . DB_DEVELOP_TEMP  can be whatever you want, from DB_DEVELOP_TEMP to DB_DEVELOP, to [I Like bad database names].

OK, I run the Command in the New Query window and how can I than get the path of my existing database when its on the company SQL server ? Im sorry im new to the SSMS... @ThomA

I suggest you talk to your DBA then, @jakubpodhaisky ; they will know what they are doing, and can explain. If you don;t know where your database files are, you also likely don't have permissions to BACKUP or RESTORE, so you won't e able to do what you want to do. Your DBA, however, will be able to.

@ThomA I would usually do the issue is that we do not have a DBA at the moment.. the old one left and Im stuck with this issue. If I could ask a DBA I would not ask a question on SO
